# How many Chinese characters are there in the world?

Tags: characters

How many Chinese characters are there in the world? I'm not sure there is a fixed answer, so you can tell me how many Chinese characters there are roughly. I will be very grateful for any answers.

Comment: Besides knowing how many "characters" there are, it should be noted that each character, (like words in any language) has more than one meaning. Thus the "meanings" attached to the characters far exceed the characters themselves, without even considering "compounds".

Comment: @WayneCheah, yes you are right.

Comment: There seems to be no fixed answer…

Comment: There are tons of weird, never-used characters in the Extended CJK part of Unicode.

Comment: @Becky 李蓓 Stupid act. Erase all, people still can read it. I don't really think you are qualified as a moderator though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the largest Chinese character database “CNS11643中文標準交換碼全字庫” has [a page](https://www.cns11643.gov.tw/wordCount.jsp?ID=0&SN=&lang=tw) which mentioned some figures:

> 全字庫
>
> 編碼字符數：116,327
>
> 現有字符數：108,633

Unicode

> 字面0：39,175
>
> 字面2：48,793
>
> 字面15：20,665

Total is: 108,633

A simple answer to your question is: **more than a lakh**.